# Combine the results of a sql query together in one result

Tags: c#, sql, addition

I have an application(C#) that manages a stock level for every storage unit.
But now i want a complete overview of the stock level of every product from every stock unit together.

For example i have `50` apples (ProductID 1) in unit one and `25` in unit two and I use this query:

```
 select StockLevel 
   from Supply 
  where ProductID = '1'
```

And put the result in a textbox it will always gives me the first stocklevel of **50** apples and not **75**.

Is there a way i can combine these results in an easy way?

Comment: [`Union`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) is ur friend.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava was about to say that

Comment: You can use `union` (no duplicate) else use `union all`.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez its one and the same thing friend.

Comment: what result do you want? do you want to display 50,25 in your textbox?

Comment: Eh, `sum`? `select sum(StockLevel) from Supply where ProductID = '1'` and get `125` (`= 50 +75`)

Comment: Do you have separate databases for each "unit"? Or do you have two records in `StockLevel` with productId=1

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (But not 75 rows here, 5 or 10 is better in examples.)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Agree with you `sum` he needed

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you were right i needed 'sum'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *combine*, you want an *aggregate function*, `sum` in your case:

```
 select sum(StockLevel)
   from Supply
  where ProductID = '1'
```

and get the apples being summed up: `75` which is `50 + 25`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT (select sum(stock) from tablename where ProductID = 1) + (select sum(stock) from tablename where ProductID  =1) as result
```